# How to produce right of way in FIFO mode in SUMO

Tags: sumo

I want vehicles to enter a junction in FIFO mode,
when speed mode is 'right of way' the priority is constant per road per simulation.
When i don't use 'right of way' i get collisions.
Is there any way to avoid collision when right of way is disabled?
Or is there any way to specifically define the right of way to work in fifo mode

Answer (score 0):

There is the junction type allway_stop which might do roughly what you want. Just try it out by changing the junction type in netedit.

Comment: thanks, 
I've checked this option and the problem is that vehicles will always halt before junctions, but if the roads are empty i don't want the vehicle to stop or slow down before the junction.

Comment: In sumo vehicles will always slow down if they cannot be 100% sure that they have the right of way, but I agree that having a junction type which lets not stop them would be feasible. I opened a ticket https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/7447